# How can I remove large amounts of duct tape from a door?

Tags: cleaning, home, efficiency

I need to remove large amounts of colored duct tape from an old, rusty door.  What is the cheapest and easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can u peel it off and you're worried about how to get the residual glue off? Or you actually cannot peel it off?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

1. Soak the duct tape in a few sprays of WD40 and if you can spray any
   beneath the tape, that would be best.
2. Start peeling the tape with a scraper or a putty knife or a blade or
   by hand.
3. Spray more WD40 over the peeled off duct tape and let it soak for 5
   minutes or so and then scrape some more.

**Optionally**

If you have any SOS Pads or steel wool, consider scrubbing the soaked duct residue with it as well.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't that create stains on the door from the dyes in the tape?

Answer (score 1):

Heat it by leaving it in the sun, pouring hot water, or else heat gun/hair dryer.  This will soften the adhesive and allow you to peel off the tape.

Remove residue with non-polar solvents (anything oily).

Answer (score 1):

Heat the tape and use a paint scraper or try to peel it off the door, if that does not work, then pour hot water and try then.
Also, if there is some of the glue left on the door, take another strip of tape and repeatedly put it on the area with the residue and then take it off again.

Answer (score 1):

I have used brake cleaner to very easily remove glue residue.  You can get it at home depot or an autoparts store.

Answer (score 1):

After removing the layer of the duck tape by heating it with something like a hair drier, use dish washing sponge and warm water and baking powder to remove the adhesive residue.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you a serious of methods. All you need is a [blade](http://g02.a.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1xUBSJpXXXXaYXFXXq6xXFXXXw/DIY-modeling-tools-utility-knife-utility-knife-large-pencil-sharpener-transparent-art-knife-blade-benefits.jpg), spray bottle,oil and some kerosene.

1. By blade, try to peel out edge of tape that is stuck on door.
2. If you can get a [spray bottle](http://images.containerstore.com/catalogimages/148194/12ozSprayBot176010_x.jpg), take some oil and water mixture.
3. When you start peeling off from door, do not try to give it a full shot. Because, tape may break and you will have to do step 1 again.
4. Instead apply force randomly. In between, if you find it tough to pull, soak adhesive part of tape with liquid taken in spray bottle and wait for it to take action.

In the case of oil, I would prefer you to use vegetable oil that you use in your home as a common lubricant. After taking away entire tapes, you can give door a nice rub with kerosene to remove left back adhesive particles.

Answer (score 0):

If the plan is to clean and paint this old rusty door I would use a hand held propane torch and burn it off.
Then scrape or wire brush it.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Most metal doors have [non-metal interiors](https://www.angieslist.com/articles/5-things-know-about-steel-door.htm) (e.g. wood).

Answer (score -1):

Use a sander, very easy and no hardwork required

Comment: Can you expand on that single line? As it stands it does not make much sense and is in risk of deletion as not enough of an answer.

Comment: I thought the answer was self explanatory. I meant use a sander, which is a device used to sand wood. It can be used because low grain sand is cheap and sanding the door would remove the tape.